# How to calculate the mean for each pixel value?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to calculate the mean for each pixel value and how to show them separatly.for example: 
Mean 124.34(red),124.44(green),124.67(blue),123.56(gray)
I try like this...

```
 import numpy as np
 import math 
 img = Image.open('cameraman.jpg')
 h,w=img.size 
 #print(h,w)
 arr = np.array(img)
 total = 0 
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
      for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            total+=arr[(i,j)]
  a=h*w
mean=(total)/a
print("Mean Value is: ",np.mean)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the average colour of an image in Python with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111029/how-to-find-the-average-colour-of-an-image-in-python-with-opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest answer ([by Ruan B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112217/10699171)  ):

```
import cv2
import numpy
myimg = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(myimg, axis=0)
avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)
print(avg_color)
```

Result:

```
     Blue           Green          Red
[ 197.53434769  217.88439451  209.63799938]
```

More extended, similar to you own method:
If you use opencv, accessing a pixel returns an array with the BGR colors.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg')

totalBlue = 0
totalGreen = 0
totalRed = 0
totalPixels = 0

for line in img:
    for px in line:
        totalBlue += px[0]
        totalGreen += px[1]
        totalRed += px[2]
        totalPixels += 1

meanBlue = totalBlue/totalPixels
meanGreen = totalGreen/totalPixels
meanRed = totalRed/totalPixels
```

To get the gray average you can load you image as a black and white image using

```
img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg', 0)
```

Comment: Thanks.
But how can I get gray value?