# How To Delete Sub Arrays In Numpy IF Exactly Matches 0,0,0

Tags: python, numpy

I'm analyzing image color, but am getting rid of any RGB color pixel that is 0,0,0 (black). [(Using this top answer as reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111029/how-to-find-the-average-colour-of-an-image-in-python-with-opencv)

I have an array of pixels

```
pixels = np.float32(img.reshape(-1, 3))

[[ 126.   94.   51.]
 [ 171.  115.   65.]
 [ 188.  119.   64.]
 ..., 
 [   0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.]]
```

I then try to go through and delete any sub arrays that are black.

```
pixelstoignore = np.delete(pixels, np.where(pixels == [0,0,0]), axis=0)
```

This appears to works:
[image]

However the difference between the average color and dominant color tell you otherwise. The Average color is working correctly.
Here is my picture:

[image]

What appears to be happening, is my code is deleting any subarray containing a 0. For example the red above has an RGB value as 255,0,0. My code is deleting this. But I only want to delete it if all 3 values are 0!

I got the average to work using np.all, but I can't get this to work with the delete function. Help!

EDIT: Solution seems to be this:

```
pixelstoignore = np.delete(pixels, np.where((pixels == [0,0,0]).all(axis=1)), axis=0)
```

Comment: This looks like a bug in `delete` to me - it should not be accepting a tuple argument.

Comment: One question though, I understood how to remove the whole row having just zeroes and I've got it, though what I don't get it is, won't that have an issue on your actual image which have to have specific shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to remove pixels where any value is 0, or just ones where all are?

```
In [212]: arr = np.array([[ 126.,   94.,   51.],
     ...:  [ 171.,  0.,   65.],
     ...:  [ 188.,  119.,   64.],
     ...:  [   1. ,   0.,    0.],
     ...:  [   0. ,   0.,    0.],
     ...:  [   0. ,   1.,    0.]])
     ...:  
     ...:  
In [213]: arr
Out[213]: 
array([[126.,  94.,  51.],
       [171.,   0.,  65.],
       [188., 119.,  64.],
       [  1.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   0.]])
In [214]: arr == [0,0,0]
Out[214]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
In [215]: np.where(arr == [0,0,0])
Out[215]: (array([1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5]), array([1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]))
```

To test for all in a 'row':

```
In [216]: (arr == [0,0,0]).all(axis=1)
Out[216]: array([False, False, False, False,  True, False])
In [217]: np.where((arr == [0,0,0]).all(axis=1))
Out[217]: (array([4]),)

In [218]: np.where((arr == [0,0,0]).any(axis=1))
Out[218]: (array([1, 3, 4, 5]),)
```

Your `delete` and `where` is only as good as the conditional inside the `where`.

Comment: _"our delete and where is only as good as the conditional inside the where"_ it's worse than that - combining `delete` and `where` just always does the wrong thing. `delete` reinterprets the `i, j` tuple returned by `where` as a 2d array of `i` values - the result is just garbage - `np.delete(a, ([1, 2], [3, 4]), 0)` is the same as `np.delete(a, [1, 2, 3, 4], 0)`

Comment: Thanks man. `pixelstoignore = np.delete(pixels, np.where((pixels == [0,0,0]).all(axis=1)), axis=0)` Seems to do it.

Comment: I think the above works as the following - `np.where((pixels == [0,0,0]).all(axis=1)) `locates the position in the array where all 3 columns equal 0. `np.delete(, axis=0)` then goes through and deletes the rows that are true.