# How to extract color using openCV

Tags: c, opencv

Hellow there~
I'm working to make app.
This app need feature that detect Rubik's cube color(Realtime).
I'm using OpenCV to implement the feature.
I try to set up ROI and I detect color in ROI.
I know how to detect specific color.
I used inRange function on hsv channel image.
It's good working.
But now I don't know how to check color on specific region.
Forexample,
rubik's cube color array
(00)Red/(01)Blue/(02)Blue
(10)Green/(11)White/(12)Orange
(20)Yellow/(21)Blue/(22)White.
I want to know (0,0)'s color. It's red.
I use inRange function like this inRange((0,0)_image, lower_color, upper_color, color_mask).
Now how to check (0,0)_image's color what is?
How to know that is red?
Thank you for your attention.
Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your image into HSV color space, where H stands for `hue` -- that's the color. Hue 0 is red, 0.3 is about green, 0.7 is like blue, you'll figure it out quite easily.

[image: color bar]

Comment: I know that. But I don't know what is color? It mean "How do I determine which color categories the pixels fall into?"

Comment: @DWhy you may use something like a pixel clustering approach, that will put all your pixels into a several bins, please, check this post about finding the dominant colors of an image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111029/how-to-find-the-average-colour-of-an-image-in-python-with-opencv