# Trouble with Cluster Module Spectral Cluster import of Scikit-Learn, install is functioning with other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, scikit-learn

I am trying to do Kmeans with sklearn and I am getting weird error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kmean_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cluster.spectral'
```

Working on Windows, I tried importing in Jupyter and just running a simple script from command.

I have tested my install of Scikit-Learn with the following imports and they work fine.

```
from sklearn import datasets

from sklearn import naive_bayes
```

First bit of code that i get the traceback error looks like:

```
import cv2, numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def visualize_colors(cluster, centroids):
...
```

I got this import code

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

from two tutorial sources but perhaps it is the problem? I have made attempts to import otherways but been unsuccessful

Just in case it was the sklearn install and because of reading through other stackoverflow suggestions I have:

I have tried uninstall and reinstall of numpy (with and without mkl), pandas, scikit-learn, and scipy both from regular command and admin command.

I have tried update as well.

I have downloaded the wheels and run install as administrator.

I am new. Please be kind. I am new to Windows development as well, Ugh! So if it has something to do with some complicated Windows system setup and software install etc etc I may not follow. I have spent 2 days trying to solve this one on my own and finally decided to reach out.

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

As per suggested below I have confirmed I do have the most recent version of sklearn 0.21.3

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
0.21.3
```

For the record here are my versions of the others:

```
python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

```
import numpy
numpy.version.version
'1.17.2'
```

```
import scipy
scipy.version.version
'1.3.1'
```

```
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__
'0.24.2'
```

Finally I would like to mention that I have been able to successfully apply Kmeans to my project without sklearn, however, I am trying to access the % and RGB values of the means. I have found two people showing how to do it and BOTH use sklearn. See here end comment by nathancy on why I am trying to install sklearn to do this specific thing: [How to find the average colour of an image in Python with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111029/how-to-find-the-average-colour-of-an-image-in-python-with-opencv/58177484#58177484)

Answer (score 0):

You have installed an older version of `sklearn.`

**`from sklearn.cluster import KMeans` with work only if you have the latest `sklearn` version which is `0.21.3`**

To check the version use:

```
import sklearn

print(sklearn.__version__)
```

Finally install sklearn latest version:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: I have confirmed i do have the latest version of sklearn. 0.21.3

Comment: try this: `pip uninstall scikit-learn ; sudo pip install scikit-learn`. Youn sklearn installation is broken

Comment: There is no sudo command for Windows. I already did the equivalent which is running as Admin as mentioned above. Also other modules of sklearn are working just fine.