# How to calculate the color pixel value in each row and column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, mean, pixel

I am working with an example of how to calculate the value of each pixel in each row and column using the following formula using Python.

Formula is
[image]

where M represents image matrix dimension N represents total number
of pixels and P(i, j) is the color pixel value at ith row and jth column

Comment: what do you want to compute, mean of the pixel values?

Comment: yes You are right I need to compute mean of pixel value and the  Shape of the image is : (204, 220, 3)

Comment: Do you want to compute the mean value for every channel(red_mean, green_mean, blue_mean) or the overall mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy if you re using python

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 

img = cv2.imread('img.png')
# in case of overall mean
np.mean(img)

#in case of channel wise mean
np.mean(img, axis=(0, 1))
```

This can be applied if your matrix has rectangular shape

Comment: thanks for your comment can u please explain me with an example so that i can clearly understand.

Answer (score 1):

The average of the pixel channels is fairly trivial to calculate, but not necessarily very meaningful - depending on the use case it is more illustrative to find the dominant colors. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43111221/10659910) demonstrates an approach to finding the dominant colors.

Here is a toy example for finding the channel-wise means of the image pixels using the image

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('opencvtest.png')

# Find the average of each channel across the image
mean = [np.mean(im[:,:,i]) for i in range(im.shape[2])]

print(mean)
```

```
[132.6709785196566, 92.74899063496903, 81.57176387455432]
```

So the average color the code found is

[image]

which is consistent with what I would expect from looking at the test image.

Comment: Thank you this is the one which I need.